# Freescale armhf iMX6Q board doesn't boot with kernel 5.10 or greater

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, u-boot

I am upgrading the kernel from version 3.17.0-rc4 to latest kernel version in a board that uses a iMX6Q Freescale processor, but the board doesn't finish to boot.

I am cross-compiling using Debian 10 following these steps:

```
cp arch/arm/configs/imx_v6_v7_defconfig .config
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- menuconfig
make -j`nproc` ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -k zImage modules
```

And then copying the zImage and modules to the boot and root partition.

My uEnv.txt file is:

```
loadaddr=0x10008000
fdtaddr=0x18000000

fdtfile=imx6q-CIO100X50V01.dtb

console=ttymxc1,115200n8
optargs=console=ttyS0 quiet systemd.show_status=false
ethaddr=70:B3:D5:16:20:00

mmcroot=/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro
mmcrootfstype=ext4 rootwait fixrtc

loadkernel=load mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${loadaddr} zImage
loadinitrd=load mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} 0x12A00000 initrd.img; setenv initrd_size ${filesize}
loadfdt=load mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${fdtaddr} /${fdtfile}

#zImage/initrd.img:
#boot_fdt=run loadkernel; run loadinitrd; run loadfdt

#zImage:
boot_fdt=run loadkernel; run loadfdt

mmcargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${mmcroot} rootfstype=${mmcrootfstype} video=${video} ethaddr=${ethaddr}

#zImage:
uenvcmd=run boot_fdt; run mmcargs; bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
```

I got this message trying to use kernel version 5.13.12, and then the boot freezes:

```
U-Boot 2016.07-rc1-g0b9fdb5-dirty (Oct 20 2016 - 15:57:37 +0200)

CPU:   Freescale i.MX6Q rev1.2 at 792 MHz
Reset cause: POR
Board: SABRE Lite
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  512 MiB
force_idle_bus: sda=0 scl=0 sda.gp=0xcb scl.gp=0x5
force_idle_bus: failed to clear bus, sda=0 scl=0
MMC:   FSL_SDHC: 0, FSL_SDHC: 1
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   No ethernet found.
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0(part 0) is current device
280 bytes read in 32 ms (7.8 KiB/s)
Running bootscript from mmc ...
## Executing script at 12000000
6x_bootscript -> uEnv.txt wrapper...
787 bytes read in 49 ms (15.6 KiB/s)
10801304 bytes read in 38345 ms (274.4 KiB/s)
33124 bytes read in 52 ms (622.1 KiB/s)
Kernel image @ 0x10008000 [ 0x000000 - 0xa4d098 ]
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 18000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x18000000
   Using Device Tree in place at 18000000, end 1800b163

Starting kernel ...


[    0.224790] debugfs: Directory 'dummy-iomuxc-gpr@20e0000' with parent 'regmap' already present!
```

I've tried with another kernel versions and I am not having issues (eg. 4.19 or 5.9), but for some reason kernel version greater than or equal to 5.10, freezes the boot.

I thought about just use 5.9 kernel version, but I am a bit salty because I don't know what it's going on and I don't know how to debug what's happening. It's something I can do to debug what's happening or something I can try?

Maybe for some reason iMX6Q is not compatible with kernel greater than 5.10? I have searched but could not find anything.

Comment: You are talking about the mainline kernel, not the NXP kernel, I suppose? There could be tousands of problems introduced by new kernel features where you'd need to adapt the defconfig or the device tree. You'll need to verbosely output all kernel messages to the console to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Hello @Philippos, yes, I am talking about mainline kernel. Should I better use NXP specific kernel? I am updating the kernel because I want to use docker on the device, I've managed to let docker running using Debian 10 and version 4.19.205, but I am getting problems to start the containers, so I want to try with kernel version 5 or greater. How I can verbosely otuput all kernel messages?

Comment: @Philippos I've forget to mention that I've tested latest NXP kernel and it freezes at the same point...

Comment: You should only need to pass a `console` parameter to the kernel in U-Boot, II think, like `console=ttymxc1,115200` for UART1 and 115,2 kbaud

Comment: @Philippos actually I have a console parameter on my uEnv.txt, I've edited my post to show the uEenv.txt file. Should I add or remove something? By the way, I've solved my problem with docker, but I want to know why I can't use kernels greater than  or queal to 5.10.

Comment: I don't know what the `quite` in `optargs` means, but it sounds like it could be the reason for the kernel to be quite.

Comment: @Philippos yep, I removed `quiet` option and now I can see the entire log, thank you. I will try to find some time to test the kernel, but probably will check it the monday, thank you for everything!

Comment: The problem may not be related to the last message you see, but to the first message you don't see (so check what comes next when using a booting kernel). Good luck! If you find the problem, give yourself the solution at an answer for future users.